# preg_replace pattern (any symbol, any length)

Tags: preg-replace

What could be a `preg_replace` pattern to change anything within quotes that is being assigned to `$my_variable`, regardless of length?

For example,

```
$my_variable = "whatever it is"
```

should be changed so that it reads:

```
$my_variable = "whatever new value"
```

Comment: I really don't understand what you are asking here? If you want to replace "anything" for "something" you don't need a regular expression. You'd just use str_replace() for that.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
/\$my_variable=\"(.*?)\";/
```